# WordPress: image used on a page(s)

Tags: wordpress, media

Looking for a plugin or hook or filter that I can use to list the pages an image is being used on. When the client goes to delete an image from the library, they want to know if it is being used on the site before deleting. Thanks!

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-posts-using-attachment/ or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/find-the-post-an-attachment-is-attached-to Might help.

Comment: Thanks @BOZ, these both look very promising.